# How to join/merge different columns of date, year, month to a single column

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the 3 separate columns of year, month and date and I want to merge/join them in a new column

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year' : [2016, 2016, 2016, 2016],
                   'month' : [1,1,1,1],
                   'day' : [1,2,3,4]}, dtype = 'datetime64[ns]')
```

expected output : A new column 'Date' populated with data from 3 columns.

```
[In] df2['Date'] 
[Out] 0 2016-01-01
      1 2016-01-02
      3 2016-01-03
      4 2016-01-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year' : [2016, 2016, 2016, 2016],
               'month' : [1,1,1,1],
               'day' : [1,2,3,4]})
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[['year','month','day']])
df2

    year    month   day     date
0   2016    1        1  2016-01-01
1   2016    1        2  2016-01-02
2   2016    1        3  2016-01-03
3   2016    1        4  2016-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
df = df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime)    
print(df['date'])

0   2016-01-01
1   2016-01-02
2   2016-01-03
3   2016-01-04
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```